# How to update Json with new content from another Json (merge Json) in javax?

Tags: java, json

I need to compare two Json: old and new. But I only need to update the old json with new content from the new json. For example:

oldJson.json:

```json
[
  {
    "thumbnail": "1"
  },
  {
    "thumbnail": "2"
  }
]
```

newJson.json:

```json
[
  {
    "thumbnail": "1"
  },
  {
    "thumbnail": "2"
  },
  {
    "thumbnail": "3"
  }
]
```

Desired outcome for `oldJson.json`:

```json
[
  {
    "thumbnail": "1"
  },
  {
    "thumbnail": "2"
  },
  {
    "thumbnail": "3"
  }
]
```

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Jsons are `JsonArray`, hence the need of `Json.createDiff(source.asJsonArray(), target.asJsonArray());`, instead of `Json.createDiff(source.asJsonObject(), target.asJsonObject());`

Please see comments in code for further details.

Also for reference please visit [Comparing JSON documents in Java with JSON-P](https://cassiomolin.com/2019/08/08/comparing-json-documents-in-java-with-jsonp/)

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder;
import javax.json.JsonPatch;
import javax.json.JsonValue;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path oldJsonPath = Paths.get("./oldJson.json");
        Path newJsonPath = Paths.get("./newJson.json");

        String leftJsonDoc = Files.readString(oldJsonPath);
        String rightJsonDoc = Files.readString(newJsonPath);

        JsonValue source = Json.createReader(new StringReader(leftJsonDoc)).readValue();
        JsonValue target = Json.createReader(new StringReader(rightJsonDoc)).readValue();

        JsonPatch diff = Json.createDiff(source.asJsonArray(), target.asJsonArray());

        // Create a container to collect only operation with add
        JsonArrayBuilder container = Json.createArrayBuilder();

        // loop through JsonArray to look for JsonObject with "op: add"
        for (JsonValue jsonObj : diff.toJsonArray()) {
            // get JSONObject(s) with "op: add"
            if (jsonObj.toString().contains("op\":\"add")) {
                container.add(jsonObj.asJsonObject()); // add it to container
            }
        }
        // Build the JsonArrayBuilder with the payload
        JsonPatch payload = Json.createPatch(container.build());
        JsonValue patchedPayload = payload.apply(source.asJsonArray());
    }
}
```